# Why am I getting "No ack for postMessage onApprove() in https://www.paypal.com in 10000ms" after completing subscription signup?

Tags: paypal

After a user has signed-up for a subscription plan using the new JS SDK button, shortly after the sign-up, the SDK throws this error:

> No ack for postMessage onApprove() in https://www.paypal.com in 10000ms

This leads me to believe I have to perform some kind of acknowledgement that I received the on approve event, but I don't see anything in the docs that say I have to do this. In fact, I don't see anything close to this in the docs.

I checked the PayPal account and the subscription was setup correctly.

Can I just ignore this, or should I be doing something specific in the onApprove handler? Here's an example of what's happening now:

```
onApprove: function (data, actions) {
    console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log("actions: " + JSON.stringify(actions));
    alert(data.subscriptionID); // You can add optional success message for the subscriber here
}
```

Note, we are still in dev with this, and this will change before we go to prod, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

Are you seeing the alert with the Subscription ID? If the code is triggering you don't need to worry about the log message. Best to replace the alert with a message added/unhidden in the DOM thanking the user for their subscription. It's possible the alert is the hangup preventing acknowledgement of the message in the what's logged.

If your server needs to be notified of new subscriptions this should not come from onApprove; subscribe to the webhook PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED (this is typically the only webhook worth paying attention to for subscriptions, ignore other events)

Comment: Preston, I had the dev console open and I saw the error spill out in the console log. I do get the alert popup with the subscriptionID, so I'll just ignore the error. If you don't mind, do you have any links to where I can find a .Net example to handle the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED webhook? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Actually getting rid of that alert in the onApprove helps a lot!